# Android studio java compiler error and AAPT2 error

Tags: android, gradle

i was building an app and everything worked fine and then i had to restart my computer and when i try to build the app again it shows an error saying

```
resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.solutions.frontier.inventorymanager:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.   
failed linking references.  

C:/Users/Surafel/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-compat-27.0.2.aar/ff928148892ded877e4d915a2e50e2e1/res/values/values.xml 
error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.solutions.frontier.inventorymanager:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.   
error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark (aka com.solutions.frontier.inventorymanager:attr/colorPrimaryDark)' not found.   
error: style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.solutions.frontier.inventorymanager:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
```

and every reference of `R.id.something` is in red error: `cannot resolve symbol R`

it also says `AAPT2 error`

heres my `build.gradle` file just in case its needed

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.solutions.frontier.inventorymanager"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "rand1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

i tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it but it doesnt work

Comment: Refer this :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46988596/3974530

Comment: download hotspot shild and rebuild it will work always i have this problem

Comment: Hotspot shield...why would i need hotspot shield?

Comment: Hotspot shield...why would i need hotspot shield?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this error multiple times, i still don't know what is the exact solution, try these
1- change your project's build tools version. it's better to upgrade rather than downgrade.
2-  go back step by step in your code, it seems you are running test with espersso go remove it and try again
3- change the library versions in your apps build.gradle file